# Three table join, subquery, or something easier?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, subquery

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

This is a quick representation of a much more complicated schema. I am looking to get this implementation which is part of a larger stored proc.

So basically I am looking to obtain a result set that includes ClientId, Company Name, Setting1, Setting2 and Setting3.

So if a Company Id does not exist in the Settings Override table, then they subscribe to their respective default settings. But if they DO have an ID in the SettingsOverride table then the result set should return those settings.

[image]

So for this example the Result Set would look like this:

[image]

Comment: You need a result set that combines data from three tables.  Two `JOIN`s seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Please show what parts or related queries you can do. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: The parts of this are faqs.  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy sorry about that thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join twice:

```
select
    c.clientId,
    c.companyName,
    coalesce(so.setting1, df.setting1) setting1,
    coalesce(so.setting2, df.setting2) setting2,
    coalesce(so.setting3, df.setting3) setting3
from company c
inner join defaul_settings cs on cs.clientId = c.clientId
left join settings_override so on so.companyId = c.companyId
```

The critical part is to `left join` table `settings_override`, so companies that have no override are not excluded from the resultset. Then, you can use `colasce()` to use the default when there is no override.